# adding a lable to a newcommand in the preamble using mhchem and fancyref

Tags: numbering, labels, preamble, mhchem, fancyref

I'm using [version=4]{mhchem} and `fancyref` as packages. In `mchem`'s manual there is a code given for the preamble that allows easily to enumberate the chemical equations like the normal equations:

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\reaction@[1]{\begin{equation}\ce{#1}\end{equation}}
\newcommand\reaction@nonumber[1]%
{\begin{equation*}\ce{#1}\end{equation*}}
\newcommand\reaction{\@ifstar{\reaction@nonumber}{\reaction@}}
\makeatother
```

as I want to label these equations for refering to them, I changed the second line to `\newcommand\reaction@[2]{\begin{equation}\ce{#1}\end{equation} \label{eq:#2}}`
which does in principal work.
However when i refer to them with `\fref{eq:label}` they have the number of the chapter.section.subsection where the equation is placed and not the number given behind the equation.
When I use instead the code `\begin{equation}\ce{Formula}\label{eq:Formula}\end{equation}` the referencing works fine and I get the number of the equation.

Does anyone can help me what is wrong with my modification of the preamble?

Here a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{fancyref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\reaction@[2]{\begin{equation}\ce{#1}\end{equation}\label{eq:#2}}
\newcommand\reaction@nonumber[1]%
{\begin{equation*}\ce{#1}\end{equation*}}
\newcommand\reaction{\@ifstar{\reaction@nonumber}{\reaction@}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{Fuel Cell}
\section{General}
\subsection{Fundamentals}
The basic reaction of a hydrogen fuel cell  is very simple, as \fref{eq:FC} shows. To gain electric energy these reaction must be separated into the hydrogen oxidation reaction (HOR, \fref [plain]{eq:HOR}) which occurs at the >anode and the oxygen reduction reaction (ORR, \fref[plain]{eq:ORR}) at the >cathode. To maintain electroneutrality, the negative current flow has to be >compensated via ionic cunduction between the electrodes. For this an >electrolyte has to be chosen which is electronically insulating but >ionically conductive. 
\reaction{H2 + 1/2O2 -> H2O}{FC} 
\reaction{H2 -> 2H+ + 2e-}{HOR}
\begin{equation}\ce{1/2O2 + 2e- -> O^2-}\label{eq:ORR}\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Try `\newcommand\reaction@[2]{\begin{equation}\ce{#1}\label{eq:#2}\end{equation}}`, i.e., place the label inside the equation

Comment: Oh, that makes scence and solved the problem. Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
\newcommand\reaction@[2]{\begin{equation}\ce{#1}\label{eq:#2}\end{equation}}
```

that is, place `\label` inside the equation in your definition, just like you do when you write

```
\begin{equation}\ce{1/2O2 + 2e- -> O^2-}\label{eq:ORR}\end{equation}
```